# Setting editable on a NSTextField doesn't have any effect

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstextfield

I have an `NSTextField` in a view that is bound to a value in the view's view controller. When a button is pressed I wish to make the text field no longer editable so I use the following code:

```
- (IBAction)makeTextFieldNotEditable:(id)sender {
    self.textField.editable = NO;
}
```

Everything is bound correctly and I can confirm that the above method gets called when I press the button but the text field is still editable. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was because by default when you bind the value of an `NSTextField` in Interface Builder it ticks the box **Conditionally Sets Editable** meaning that the value the text field is bound to sets the `editable` property of the text field.

Unticking this box made my original code work.

Comment: **Conditionally Sets Editable** also gets set to `true`, if you bind programmatically. In that case you have to set it to `false`:             `textfield.bind("value", to: arrayController, withKeyPath: "selection.text", options: [NSConditionallySetsEditableBindingOption: false])`